# My recycler view not showing list items but in my log they are visible

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have use two recycler view in my app in one recycler view there was direct entry to the list and the other one have firebase database.
when I am running my app the first recycler view is working but the second recycler view was not showing but in logs it has retrieve data from firebase properly please help me showing data to recycler view.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#f2f2f2">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/recyclerView"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerMenuView"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Mainactivity.java - firebase recycler viw are menu() and getmenu()

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference reference;

    ArrayList<dish> list;



    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private ArrayList<String> mCategory = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getCategory();
        menu();


    }

    private void getCategory(){
        Log.d(TAG, "Preparing Categories");

        mCategory.add("Vagetables");
        mCategory.add("Indian Bread");
        mCategory.add("Paranthas");
        mCategory.add("Starters");
        mCategory.add("Snacks");
        mCategory.add("Salad");
        mCategory.add("Noodles");
        mCategory.add("Sandwiches");
        mCategory.add("Rice");
        mCategory.add("Soups");
        mCategory.add("Beverages");
        mCategory.add("Yoghurt");
        mCategory.add("Papad");

        initRecyclerView();
    }

    private void initRecyclerView(){
        Log.d(TAG, "init RecyclerView");
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, mCategory);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }



  private void menu(){
      list = new ArrayList<dish>();
      Log.d(TAG, "recycler MenuView : Firebase Initialized");

      FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
      reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("dishes");
      reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange : called");
              for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
              {
                  Log.d(TAG,"Adding Menu");
                  dish p = dataSnapshot1.getValue(dish.class);
                  Log.d(TAG, "called : " + p);
                  Log.d(TAG, " : " + dataSnapshot + " : " + dataSnapshot1);
                  list.add(p);
              }

          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Opps....Somethinf Went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
      });

      getmenu();
  }

    private void getmenu(){
        Log.d(TAG,"Setting adapter");
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerMenuView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerMenuView);
        recyclerMenuView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


        MenuAdapter adapter = new MenuAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);

        recyclerMenuView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


}
```

````
Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1123403393
V/FA: Session started, time: 1123403991
D/FA: Setting user property (FE): _sid, 1562093111
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/FA: Logging event (FE): session_start(_s), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-756514691701175737, session_id(_sid)=1562093111}]
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 6
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@8162696
D/MainActivity: onDataChange : called
D/MainActivity: Adding Menu
D/MainActivity: called : com.example.myapplication.dish@f142604
D/MainActivity:  : DataSnapshot { key = dishes, value = {chilipaneer={dishImage=https://github.com/cb2609/Credit-Management-App/blob/master/food/chilli_paneer.jpg, permission=true, dishname=Chili Paneer, dishrate=Rs.170}, paneertikka={dishImage=https://github.com/cb2609/Credit-Management-App/blob/master/food/paneer_tikka.jpg, permission=true, dishname=Paneer Tikka, dishrate=Rs.150}} } : DataSnapshot { key = chilipaneer, value = {dishImage=https://github.com/cb2609/Credit-Management-App/blob/master/food/chilli_paneer.jpg, permission=true, dishname=Chili Paneer, dishrate=Rs.170} }
D/MainActivity: Adding Menu
D/MainActivity: called : com.example.myapplication.dish@a4197ed
     : DataSnapshot { key = dishes, value = {chilipaneer={dishImage=https://github.com/cb2609/Credit-Management-App/blob/master/food/chilli_paneer.jpg, permission=true, dishname=Chili Paneer, dishrate=Rs.170}, paneertikka={dishImage=https://github.com/cb2609/Credit-Management-App/blob/master/food/paneer_tikka.jpg, permission=true, dishname=Paneer Tikka, dishrate=Rs.150}} } : DataSnapshot { key = paneertikka, value = {dishImage=https://github.com/cb2609/Credit-Management-App/blob/master/food/paneer_tikka.jpg, permission=true, dishname=Paneer Tikka, dishrate=Rs.150} }
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service```
````

Comment: can you share some screenshots. i suspect something to do with your layout not being proper

Comment: Set the height of you recyclerMenuView to wrappcontent . And secondly while fetchign data from firebase , just notify the adpter when you recieve the complete list . For this you need to initialise your adapter before your firebase call . This might be the case , data taking long time to load and before that adapter is set with empty list .

Comment: Try calling getmenu() at the end of for loop in onDataChange method of firebase .

Comment: U set adapter for second recycleView before u get data. App gets data async form firebase. So put adapter as a field and call notifiDataSetChanged() on it when data from firebase are loaded